# Create a method that returns a class and then access the variables

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class `Fruits` that consists of certain variables:

```
public class Fruits {
  public static String abc="something";
}

public class Apple extends Fruits {
  public static String abc="something";
}
```

Depending on the config it selects whether it should return an instance of `Fruits` or `Apple`:

```
Class Fruits{
  public static Fruits getfruit{
    if(config==3) {
      return new Apple();
    } else {
      return new Fruits();
    }
  }
}
```

So later I can use `Utility.getfruit().abc`.

Comment: Sorry, do you want to create a class based on a property/configuration?

Comment: a Class doesn't have access to instance methods. Instances of the class do. You are trying to call constructors, but you forget the ()'s, like: return new Procedures();
It's also String, not string, and to clarify, your classes don't have instance variables

Comment: @Andre yes something like that

Comment: @SSinha 1500 variables (from the other comments, information is *missing* in question) is a bit much... maybe you should think about a different data model (`Map`, `List`, ...)

Comment: @SSinha please have a look - https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Just use instance variables instead of static variables and two objects of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

If `abc` is gonna be always the same you can just keep the one in the parent class, you will always be able to access it whether your instance is of a parent or a child class.

If the value of `abc` is different per child class, create a method `public String getAbc()` in the parent class and override it in each child that needs a different value:

```java
public class Fruits {
   public static string abc="something";

   public String getAbc() {
      return abc;
   } 
}

public class Apple extends Fruits {
   public static string abc="something different";

   @Override
   public String getAbc() {
      return abc;
   } 
}
```

And so, in your final call use it this way:

```java
Utility.getfruit().getAbc();
```

Comment: Thanks I understood but a little problem I have over more than 1500 variables so do I have to generate getter for all ?

Comment: You can give it a try using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). Although I don't know if they have something for gettters for static fields.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in the parent class `Fruits` and override that method in child class `Apple` .

when you call that method with instance that you got from `getfruit` will work.

> sample code

```
public class UtilityDemo {​​​​
    static int config = 3;
    public static Fruits getfruit() {​​​​
        if (config == 3) {​​​​
            return new Fruits();
        }​​​​ else
            return new Apple();
    }​​​​

    public static void main(String args[]) {​​​​
        System.out.println(getfruit().getAbc());
    }​​​​
}​​​​


public class Fruits {​​​​
    public static String abc = "From Fruits";
    public String getAbc() {​​​​
        return abc;
    }​​​​
}​​​​


public class Apple extends Fruits {​​​​
    public static String abc = "From Apple";
    @Override
    public String getAbc() {​​​​
        return abc;
    }​​​​
}​​​​
```

Comment: but why is there a need for an instance? There aren't instance variables.

Comment: Thanks I understood but a little problem I have over more than 1500 variables so do I have to generate getter for all ?

Comment: they are not instance variables but Question asked is they want instance of class right? @Stultuske

Comment: That's how it is @SSinha we need to generate Getters and Setters for all the variables.

Comment: @SRMKumar yes, the question is, the example provided isn't.